# Кот ученый

Tags: литература

Об ученом коте тут уже шла речь, но у меня немного другой вопрос.
Возможно, об этом написано немало статей, не знаю. Поэтому все-таки спрошу.
Пушкин описывает достаточно нетривиальный образ: кот, который ходит по цепи вокруг дуба и рассказывает сказки (как тут не вспомнить: "– Ну-с, так… – сказал хорошо поставленный мужской голос. – В некотором было царстве, в некотором государстве жил-был царь, по имени… мнэ-э… ну, в конце концов, неважно. Скажем, мнэ-э… Полуэкт… У него было три сына-царевича. Первый… мнэ-э-э… Третий был дурак, а вот первый?..").
Так вот, мне стало интересно: этот необычный образ - плод воображения великого поэта, или тот все-таки взял за основу какие-то народные сказания? Тогда интересно, как могли такие сказания появиться и что они описывали?

Comment: Мне сразу вспоминается монолог Задорнова "Хатуль мадан": http://vk.com/video151920834_170958734 )))))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще прототипом кота учёного является кот Баюн из русских (а, вероятней, даже славянских) сказок. У Пушкина этот образ имеет ряд изменений для того, чтобы сделать персонажа более положительным. В оригинале Баюн является огромным котом, живущим в глухих местах, вроде леса, пустошей, где он может сидеть как на камне, так и на дереве, напевать песни и рассказывать истории, которые необходимы для того, чтобы усыплять путников, которых кот, впоследствии, поедал. У Пушкина ничего такого, разумеется нет. Его кот более добрый, эдакий  сказочник. Однако, ноги у этого образа растут от мифологического кота Баюна. На счёт прототипа цепи рассуждать сложно, но с металлом кот имеет очевидную связь: его когти и зубы металлические.

Отдельно хочется отметить то, что всегда находятся исследователи, которые хотят найти в подобных сказках более глубокие смыслы: космологию, либо иную мировозренческую картину. Так, в "Колобке" усматривают описание движения Солнца. Нельзя не утверждать, не отрицать подобные объяснения, а только учитывать их как возможность, как факт. В этой связи, разумеется напрашиваются следующие параллели: дуб может представлять собой мировое дерево - символ распространённый во многих мировых религиях. Сам факт движения кота по кругу можно трактовать как круговорот времени, либо траекторию движения небесных тел, но здесь мы столкнёмся с проблемой объяснения того момента, что кот может ходить в разные стороны, хотя, ничто не мешает списать это на вымысел автора, добавленный к старой легенде. Трудно судить о том, сколь подобные объяснения правдоподобны, так древние мифы (скажем, Греции, Египта, Индии) безусловно отражали именно такие, космологические понятия. Тем более, нам неизвестен Пушкинский первоисточник, ведь его стихи - это адаптированные истории, рассказанные няней, а как эти истории звучали изначально и из какого источника взяты, уточнить невозможно. В этой связи, самым правдоподобным объяснением является переработка образа кота Баюна, благо, других котов у славянских народностей известно не было. А золотая цепь, хоть небесную дорогу она символизирует, хоть млечный путь, хоть циферблат часов из 12 звеньев или месяцев, останется загадкой.

Comment: Златая (червоная) это наша радуга. Кот - один из цветов спектра (синий ).

Answer (score 0):

Баюн - это, конечно, правильно... Но почему ученый - да на цепи?
Сдается мне, что на цепи водили ученых медведей. Но медведи редко разговаривают даже в сказках. А Баюн тут как нельзя кстати. Так что это сказочный четырехлапый знаток фольклора вполне мог быть "собирательным образом": "медвекотом" или "котоведем". Дуб вполне вписывается в систему ценностей славянской "виртуальной реальности", непонятой остается только цепь из драгметалла... Но, может, просто для пущей сказочности...

(+)----------------------

Надо насчет "цепи" отдельный вопрос открывать...

Comment: А  он  не  на  цепи.  Он  по  цепи  ходит,  как  по  приспособлению  для  ходьбы.

Comment: У лукоморья дуб зеленый;

Златая цепь на дубе том:

И днем и ночью кот ученый

Всё ходит по цепи кругом;

@bernard +1

Мне кажется, НА цепи кот потому, что он СВЕРХУ цепи.  Ходит по ней. А не прикован к ней ошейником, как собака или медведь.

Comment: Могу предположить, что золотой цепью украшен **дуб**, потому что дуб - особое дерево в древности у славян и балтов.

Comment: Так  ведь  прямо  сказано  "ходит  по  цепи",  художники  так  и  рисуют.  Хотя  можно  предположить,  что  по  цепи  -  это  вдоль  цепи,  по  периметру  цепи,  но  никак  не  на  цепи  как  собака  какая.

Comment: Интересно, как ходить по цепи (в буквальном современном понимании) ходить - да еще кругом?!

Comment: Элементарно, Ватсон!  Если  цепь  обвивает  ствол  дуба,  то  кругом - это  вокруг  ствола   дуба:  сначала  в  одну  сторону  до  определённого  места,  потом  разворачивается  и  идёт  в  другую  с  другим  репертуаром.  И  дуб  в  три  обхвата,  и  цепь  как  якорная.  Кот  пройдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматривать цепь как алигорию, то это и есть "сказ"- связь событий, золотая - это поучительная сказка.

Comment: Золотая  цепь  как  аллегория  сборника  сказок  вполне  может  быть.  Но  и  простым  сказочным  приспособлением  для  ходьбы  тоже  может.